# onclick does not work during translate animation android

Tags: android

This is not a new problem. But a bit different.

There are lots of questions and answers in SOF on click not working after translate animation. I have gone through them all. But my issue is a bit different.

I am trying to move an object in the screen from button to top in the y axis. Again this is a repeat animation. So basically my button goes to the top and when reaches there, it starts from bottom again. This is quite easy with Translate animation with the help of repeatcount and repeat mode method.

Now the real problem is the click on that button does not work. And I know the reason also. What i am looking for is a solution to my requirement.

I dont think I can use Translate animation. Help me guys

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

I got a way to do this. I am using a handler to set the object topmargin by some value to move it up.

Comment: i got the same issue now, onClick not triggering while animation (using TranslateAnimation). how did you achieve this?